# PlayFramework resolves dependencies every launch

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

Every time I launch my app play resolves dependencies. Considering this happens every single launch takes a lot of time... There was a time I had problem with one lib that wasn't unavailable so the app didn't launch... Is there anyway to configure play/SBT to work like Maven? Download dependencies and use local instead resolve every launch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Add `skip in update := true` in to the *build.sbt* file to stop dependencies resolution. My *build.sbt* looks like

```
...

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

skip in update := true

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "2.1.6"
)

...
```

You can read more about dependency tuning in the typesafe sbt documentation: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Dependency-Management-Flow.html

btw, documentation says:

> if no dependency management configuration has changed since the last
>   successful resolution and the retrieved files are still present, sbt
>   does not ask Ivy to perform resolution.

I have exactly this behaviours, so I am not sure why do you have:

> Every time I launch my app play resolves dependencies

Comment: Works like a miracle!