# Why does setting up a project with play take so much time ?

Tags: java, maven, playframework

I am trying to use play framework to make a simple hello world web application. 
After downloading, it I have used `activator new helloworld` to create a simple project named helloworld and to run it I am using `activator run`.

Now, the activator is taking a lot of time to run. 
It is downloading a lot of jar files from a very long time.
I want to know, why does it download so many jar files for the project ? Will it download those jar files before running every  new project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activator is the soft wrapper for sbt. Sbt is the build tool that play use.

When you create the project `activator new` - it download (and create) the project "template" files.

When you run `activator run` sbt check your configuration and download dependencies. It's smart, so it will not download dependencies every `run` - it will update it only if you change it.

Look at this question and my answer: [PlayFramework resolves dependencies every launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049591/playframework-resolves-dependencies-every-launch)